# Write <% to a view in MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to pass the template string to my chartjs in mvc2, the template string akin to:

```
tooltipTemplate: <%if (value != 0){%><%= label %> - <%= value %><%}%>
```

How can I do that in mvc2 view? the rendering engine thinkgs that `<%` tags are c# and tries to render them.

The only thing I came up with was:

```
this.ViewData["Hack"] = "<%if (value != 0){%><%= label %> - <%= value %><%}%>";
```

but this looks bad.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can u pls elaborate in detail?

Comment: @DH__ in the resulting html that is sent to the browser I need to have:
`var stuff = { tooltipTemplate: <%if (value != 0){%><%= label %> - <%= value %><%}%> };` that is used by some jquery. How do I achieve that?

Comment: You can use &lt; and &gt; instead of < and >

Comment: @x2. tried that, doesn't work. it outputs the &lt; literally, doesn't interpret it.

Comment: Hm, then you can do something like this `<%= Server.HtmlDecode("&lt;%if (value != 0){%&gt;&lt;%= label %&gt; - &lt;%= value %&gt;&lt;%}%&gt;") %>` It's pretty ugly too, but whithout codebehind/additional variables needed.